# C# OrmLite v5.11.0 SqliteOrmLiteDialectProvider class throwing a compiler error

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, unit-testing, ormlite-servicestack

I'm trying to write a Sqlite in-memory database in C# using `ServiceStack.OrmLite` version 5.11.0 [based on the follow article from 2016](https://mikhail.io/2016/02/unit-testing-dapper-repositories/) that includes a class called `InMemoryDatabase` that looks like this:

```
using ServiceStack.OrmLite;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace akmazio_api.Classes
{
    public class InMemoryDatabase
    {
        private readonly OrmLiteConnectionFactory dbFactory = new(":memory:", SqliteOrmLiteDialectProvider.Instance);

        public IDbConnection OpenConnection() => dbFactory.OpenDbConnection();

        public void Insert<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
        {
            using var db = OpenConnection();
            db.CreateTableIfNotExists<T>();
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                db.Insert(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that I'm getting red squiggly lines underneath the `SqliteOrmLiteDialectProvider` class name and the compiler error that I'm getting is:

```
CS0103: The name 'SqliteOrmLiteDialectProvider' does not exist in the current context
```

Does anyone here know how to fix this issue so that I can get a Sqlite instance up and running in my C# application?

Please let me know if there's any additional information you need to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!  It looks like all I had to do was to install the Nuget Package `ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite` and then switch from `SqliteOrmLiteDialectProvider.Instance` to `SqliteDialect.Provider`.  Problem Solved!